# Under what geometric conditions is the image of an irrep of $H$ isomorphic to the image of an irrep of the fundamental group of $G/H$?

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, vector-bundles, connections, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ a closed subgroup. Let $\pi_1(G/H)$ denote the fundamental group of the homogeneous space $G/H$. If $\lambda$ is an irrep of $H$, then under what conditions does there exist an irrep $\rho$ of $\pi_1(G/H)$ such that
$$
  H/\mathrm{ker}(\lambda) = \pi_1(G/H)/\mathrm{ker}(\rho).
$$
In other words, under what conditions does there exist an irrep $\rho$ such that the image of $\lambda$ is isomorphic to the image of $\rho$? I am hoping for something geometric in nature (if possible).

---

If $G$ is simply connected and $H$ is discrete then it is known that $\pi_1(G/H) = H$ and so we can choose $\rho$ to be $\lambda$. However, if we drop the requirement that $H$ be discrete then more generally we have that $\pi_1(G/H) = \pi_0(H)$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1244226/767627)). It is less clear in this case when the above equation holds.

---

*Context*: This equation has come up regarding the "canonical" or "$H$-connection" one can place on the vector bundle $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G \lambda$ (that is, the "twisted vector bundle" underlying the induced representation). In particular $H/\mathrm{ker}(\lambda)$ is the "monodromy group" of the connection and $\pi_1(G/H)/\mathrm{ker}(\rho)$ seems to be related to classification of the flatness of the connection.

Comment: what is "irrep"? First time I see the term

Comment: @Masacroso It's short for "irreducible representation"

Comment: @EricKubischta - how do you pass between representations of $\pi_1(G/H)$ and $H$?

Comment: Note: If $G$ is a linear algebraic group over the complex numbers and if $\rho: \pi_1(G/H) \rightarrow GL_k(V)$ is a representation it corresponds to a flat connection $(E, D)$, where $E$ is a vector bundle. If $\eta: H \rightarrow GL_k(W)$ is a representation we get a $G$-linearized vector bundle $E(\eta)$.

Comment: @hm2020 This sounds interesting but I am not sure I totally follow. Perhaps you could expand your comment more as an answer?

Comment: @EricKubischta - It seems to me in your post you indicate there are natural functors between $\pi_1(G/H)$-modules and $H$-modules. Do I understand this correctly? If there are, you should include a definition of these functors in your post.